# Try and Catch Exception Handling

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am trying to add try and catch exception into my code but dont know where to put it into my code. Could someone please help. New to Java. I know that to have a try you need the catch. If anyone could be of any help that would be good. If you need any further details let me know :)

I also have used Page Object Modelling to write my code also.

```
package com.gms;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import NGP_IOS_Test.AttractionTab;
import NGP_IOS_Test.MyAlbum;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder;

public class pages {

AppiumDriver driver;

 public AppiumDriverLocalService service;

@BeforeTest
public void AttractionsPage() throws IOException, InterruptedException, 
MalformedURLException

{
service = AppiumDriverLocalService
          .buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder()
          .usingDriverExecutable(new 
File("/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.2.1/bin/node"))
          .withAppiumJS(new 





File("/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules
/appium/build/lib/main.js")));

  service.start();

  Thread.sleep(5000);

  DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "safari");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "10.3");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 7 Plus");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 7 Plus");
driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

  @Test
  public void RunTest() throws InterruptedException {


 driver.get("http://gms-picsolve-qa.ngpdev.com");

 AttractionTab attraction=new AttractionTab(driver);


 //click a photo
attraction.clickphoto();
Thread.sleep(3000);

//click thats me on preview
attraction.clickpreview();
Thread.sleep(3000);

//click no on facial detection 
attraction.clickFDS();
Thread.sleep(3000);


MyAlbum album=new MyAlbum(driver);

album.clickalbum();
Thread.sleep(3000);
album.photoassiston();
Thread.sleep(3000);
album.exitselfie();

}

    @AfterTest
   public void afterTest() {

 driver.quit();


service.stop();

}
}
```

Comment: "New to Java." - In that case you might want to get the basics first (and exception handling is one of them) before diving into the more complex topics. You're taking multiple steps at a time and are prone to eventually stumble and fall.

Comment: *I know that to have a try you need the catch.* Technically, no. But why would you even consider skipping the catch if you're trying to implement error handling?

Comment: What error are you trying to catch?

Answer (score 0):

Some basic rules:

- surround with `try` only the lines you think there may be an exception, and `catch` only the exception you know. Don't involve too many codes in `try`. Modern IDEs like Eclipse may help you with identifying the type of exceptions to catch. Be as specific as possible.
- But in practice, I see ppl surround as many as lines with `try` and add `catch` the generic `(Exception e)` at last, so almost all code in a whole method is in `try`. Practical, easy, but ugly. To begin quickly this is acceptable, but I suggest you to refine this when you know Java better.
- Ah, and at last, don't use `catch` to manipulate condition branch, i.e., don't substitute `if` with `try/catch`, or try your best not to do so.

---

As for your code... indent properly, and try to read Javadoc of each method to understand which exception every line may throw, and divide them in small, separated methods for clear structure. Then you can begin to think about how to use `try/catch`.

Comment: Thank you guys, do you know the best source of material i can use to learn basic java?

Comment: I suggest searching here, and reading javadoc of every method you use. As for books, I haven't read many so I am afraid I cannot recommend any. If any, Core Java newest version.